# InfluxDB calculating elapsed time between points

Tags: influxdb

I have series of values that specify the status of jobs, either success or failure.

Each item in the series has a type, and also a grouping ID. It's a dependent sequence so job `bar` for ID `A` will run if job `foo` was successful.

```
idx time                    id     type    status
1   2018-01-01T00:00:00     A      foo     success
2   2018-01-01T01:00:00     A      bar     success
3   2018-01-02T00:00:00     B      foo     success
4   2018-01-02T02:00:00     B      bar     success
5   2018-01-03T00:00:00     C      foo     success
6   2018-01-03T03:00:00     C      bar     success
7   2018-01-04T00:00:00     D      foo     success
8   2018-01-04T01:00:00     D      bar     success
9   2018-01-05T00:00:00     E      foo     success
10  2018-01-05T01:00:00     E      bar     success
11  2018-01-06T00:00:00     F      foo     failure
12  2018-01-07T00:00:00     G      foo     failure
13  2018-01-08T00:00:00     H      foo     recovery
14  2018-01-08T03:00:00     H      bar     success
15  2018-01-09T00:00:00     I      foo     failure
16  2018-01-10T00:00:00     J      foo     failure
17  2018-01-11T00:00:00     K      foo     recovery
18  2018-01-11T03:00:00     K      bar     success
```

I need to calculate the *time between dependent jobs* and  *recovery time for per job type*.

For the data above, the *time between dependent jobs* series would be:

- elapsed(1,2) (group A)
- elapsed(3,4) (group B)
- elapsed(5,6) (group C)
- elapsed(7,8) (group D)
- elapsed(9,10) (group E)
- elapsed(13,14) (group H)

And the *recovery time* series would be:

- elapsed(11, 13) (between groups F and H)
- elapsed(15, 17) (between groups I and K)

I have used the `elapsed()` and `difference()` aggregates to get what I need, but it seems inelegant.

**For the recovery time series:**

I added a "success" value to my points, with an integer number specifying 1 for "success" or "recovery", and 0 for "failure".

I used `difference()` on that to determine whether the point was a new failure (-1), repeat of previous status (0), or a recovery (+1). Filtering out the zero values gives me just failures and recoveries.

`elapsed()` on these points gives the time between failure and recovery, but also recovery and the next failure. These can be differentiated by adding `cumulative_sum()` of the diff'd successes to the final series (-1 is a failure; 0 is a recovery) and then filtering for only the recoveries.

```
SELECT elapsed FROM (
    SELECT elapsed(diff) as elapsed, cumulative_sum(diff) as csum FROM (
        SELECT diff from (
            SELECT difference(success) AS diff FROM test WHERE type = 'foo'
        ) WHERE diff != 0
    )
) WHERE csum = 0
```

Result on the above dataset:

```
time                 elapsed
----                 -------
2018-01-08T00:00:00Z 172800000000000
2018-01-11T00:00:00Z 172800000000000
```

**For the time between dependent jobs series:**

This can be done with the same trick, adding an integer value specifying the type of job. Below the value `bar` is 1 if `type = 'bar'` and 0 otherwise.

```
SELECT elapsed FROM (
    SELECT elapsed(success) as elapsed, difference(bar) as diff
        FROM test WHERE type='bar' OR (type='foo' AND success=1)
) WHERE diff = 1
```

Result on the above dataset:

```
time                 elapsed
----                 -------
2018-01-01T01:00:00Z 3600000000000
2018-01-02T02:00:00Z 7200000000000
2018-01-03T03:00:00Z 10800000000000
2018-01-04T01:00:00Z 3600000000000
2018-01-05T01:00:00Z 3600000000000
2018-01-08T03:00:00Z 10800000000000
2018-01-11T03:00:00Z 10800000000000
```

Is there a better way to do this? Either a completely different strategy, or without having to add all these integer values to my points, e.g. by applying `difference()` to a calculated field?

Most of the complexity comes from trying to select every other point from a series. Is there a better way to do that?